# Android issue creating direcory under data directoy

Tags: android

I am trying to create /data/data/package name/files directory to put my preloaded realm file as part of application start up. But the directory is not creating at all. I am not sure what mistake I am making, please point out

```
public class GlobalDataAccess: Application() {
    val TAG = "GlobalDataAccess"

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        copyRealmFile();

    }

    private fun copyRealmFile() {
        val filePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        Log.d(TAG,"**************************************************************************************************************File path =>"+filePath)
        val file = File(filePath, "data/"+getPackageName()+"/files")

        if(file.exists())
            file.delete()
        file.mkdirs()
    }
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".application.GlobalDataAccess"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't hardcode** your path. Instead use context to get your application package.

via:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

### Details

You **don't** have access to

```
data/<mypackage>/files
```

You **do** however; have access to

```
data/data/<mypackage>/files
```

Which when you use Context.getFilesDir() will return your context package in `data/data/`

Avoid hardcoding if you don't know the path. Depend on what is reliable for your usecase.

Comment: Should also note that using `getFilesDir()` will automatically create the directory for you if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create files in app's private data directory rather than SD card.
You can use this method to open a `FileOutputStream` in your app's data directory.

```
/**
 * Open a private file associated with this Context's application package
 * for writing.  Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.
 *
 * @param name The name of the file to open; can not contain path
 *             separators.
 * @param mode Operating mode.  Use 0 or {@link #MODE_PRIVATE} for the
 * default operation, {@link #MODE_APPEND} to append to an existing file,
 * {@link #MODE_WORLD_READABLE} and {@link #MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE} to control
 * permissions.
 *
 * @return FileOutputStream Resulting output stream.
 *
 * @see #MODE_APPEND
 * @see #MODE_PRIVATE
 * @see #MODE_WORLD_READABLE
 * @see #MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
 * @see #openFileInput
 * @see #fileList
 * @see #deleteFile
 * @see java.io.FileOutputStream#FileOutputStream(String)
 */
public abstract FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
    throws FileNotFoundException;
```